# name 'delta_scroll' is not defined even though I defined it?

Tags: python, pygame

so I am trying to make my enemy not scroll with my camera when it moves left and right

I someone helped me make a function to stop my enemy from scrolling all it suppose to do is not make my enemy scroll example [vid](https://gyazo.com/4fe2e851e6d0d06ea524967e2063fe6e)

```
def onscroll(enemying, delta_scroll): 
    for enemys in enemying:
        enemys.position = (enemys.position[0] - delta_scroll, enemys.position[1])
```

then on my main loop I called that function so my enemy doesnt scroll with my screen

```
    # camera left and right movement
    if playerman.y < 250:
        playerman.y += 1
        for enemys in enemying:
            enemys.y += delta_scroll
```

but for some reason I keep getting the same error

```
name 'delta_scroll' is not defined
```

[Enemy Class](https://pastebin.com/raw/NsRFz1JX)

[my full code](https://pastebin.com/raw/21QHcVmK)

Comment: It looks like `delta_scroll` is only defined within the scope of your function `onscroll`. That means that outside your function, the variable is undefined, so you get that error. Also, in the code you posted, where you say that you called the function, you don't call the function.

Comment: how do I fix this tho..

Comment: The problem is too fundamental to "fix". You need to know what your function is trying to do. Then you need to call the function, passing it the appropriate parameters, and interacting with the return of the function. None of those things are clear, from just reading your code, which indicates that you may not be certain, yourself. So there's not a quick fix. Sorry!

Comment: @HabibIsmail `onscroll` is never invoked in your code and `delta_scroll` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. What is `delta_scroll` ought to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick tip- there are a TON of `pg.image.load("myImg.png")` commands. here is a better way of doing it:

```
standingright = []
for i in range(1, 16):
    imgPath = "d"+str(i)+".png"
    img = pg.image.load(imgPath)
    standingright.append(img)
```

This is a much more concise way of loading the images. It will result in the exact same list of images in the exact same order, but I thought I would mention it to you because it will make your code much neater.

About the issue at hand: I searched your code for mentions of delta_scroll, and found it being used, but never defined. Also I saw you defined the function "onscroll", but never used it. Are you getting these two mixed up perhaps?